# Appending options to select via an AJAX request not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sort through the JSON and for all the verified users add a option to the `<select>` attribute which has a id of `verified-users-list`.

The issue is that I am trying to append the results of the verified users to HTML

```js
function getVerifiedUsers(id, url) {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', url);
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    let test = verified(ourData)
    //console.log(test);  
    $(id).append(`<option id: ${test.id}>${test.name}</option>`);
  }
  ourRequest.send();
}

function verified(data) {
  var user = {};
  var j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].verified == true) {
      user[j] = data[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return user
}

getVerifiedUsers("#verified-users-list", "http://localhost:3000/user");
```

AJAX response:

```js
[{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Yan Li",
  "verified": true
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Anna Lopez"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Bobby Patel",
  "verified": true
}]
```

Comment: Look closely at the output of `console.log(test)` - you're creating an indexed array using `user[j] = ` but then using it as a single object so your `$(id).append(` needs to be in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have done some refactoring, and this code should work.
The option markup was wrong - `id:` part. Also i have refactored verified users loop part.
The doc references you can find below.

```
function getVerifiedUsers(id, url){
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', url);
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    let verifiedUsers = verified(ourData);
    verifiedUsers.map(user => {
        $(id).append(`<option id="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>`);
    })
      
     
}
ourRequest.send();
}

// Filter only verified users
function verified(data){
    return data.filter(user => user.verified == true)
}

getVerifiedUsers("#verified-users-list", "http://localhost:3000/user");
```

For JS filter method you can reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

For JS map method you can reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I understand your code and makes sense, as when I log to console, I can see the results but it won't update the actual html <select> to include the option attribute. What else might be causing this issue?

Comment: Figured it out, in my html my     <select id=“verified-users-list”></select> had the wrong "", which was causing it to not select. :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your logic is that you have an object containing all the verified users in `test`, yet you only attempt to append a single one of them, and the syntax in that append is incorrect as it accesses the object directly, instead of the arrays in the properties.

To fix this you need to loop through the value returned from `verified()`. You can also massively simplify that function by using `filter()`. From there it's a simple call to `map()` to create an array of `option` elements to append to the relevant target `id`. Try this:

```js
function getVerifiedUsers(id, url) {
  // AJAX request here...
  
  var ourData = [{ "id": 0, "name": "Yan Li", "verified": true }, { "id": 1, "name": "Anna Lopez" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Bobby Patel", "verified": true }]
  let test = verified(ourData)
  
  let options = test.map(o => `<option id: ${o.id}>${o.name}</option>`);  
  $(id).append(options);
}

function verified(data) {
  return data.filter(i => i.verified);
}

getVerifiedUsers("#verified-users-list", "http://localhost:3000/user");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="verified-users-list"></select>
```